# Are 4 magic systems too much when it comes to a modern type of world with a lot of moving parts?

Tags: magic, super-powers, worldbuilding-process, balancing-magic-systems, supernatural

I have four power systems. Superpowers Supertechnology, Magic, and the Charles Atlas Powers. All 4 systems are not original. The systems are pretty generic. The only difference is, im just putting my own unique spin on powers in fiction.

Superpowers are like X Men or Spiderman. Magic is like Harry Potter or Dr. Strange. Super tech is like Iron Man or Black Mirror. And the Charles Atlas powers are like Batman or John Wick.

Super tech and the Charles atlas power kinda overlap a bit. Because you need smart people to make technology. I.E. Elon Musk or Iron Man. And also super tech kinda overlap with superpowers too. A mutant can be born with super intelligence as a superpower. And the biology of mutants can be technology blueprints.

So the systems do overlap a bit. But one of the biggest world changes in my world. Is the fact that muggles without powers are more dangerous than ever. You would think Mutants and Wizards would be the only threats in this world. But the Charles Atlas power can turn muggles into deadly serial killers.

But despite being the weakest power system, the system is built on human limits or potential. The Charles Atlas power users still outnumber any type of superhuman in my world. So their threats are more common. And also muggles can have access to super technology too.

So in conclusion. These are my four power systems. Is more than one magic system too much for one world?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You can certainly do multiple magic systems. Nothing is stopping you. Most superhero media often includes multiple elements of different things all rolled into one, with superheroes living right beside more traditional magic users. The problem is keeping track of them all. There have to be set limits to each system, Magic might be weak to superpowers, for example, or vice versa. It also needs to be clear when one person is using one or the other. Example, all magic users have wands and all superhumans have glowing eyes.

Comment: Too much is an entirely subjective. Additionally asking is it too much only makes sense as a question from the view of an audience. You don't see anyone asking "Is 4 fundamental forces too much?" or "Are there too many elements?"

Comment: What exactly is "Charles Atlas"? I'm not familiar and you seem to use the term as if I should be.

Comment: Hi and welcome to the community! I think you really need to open up a discussion about this problem with your audience or game peers. There are online forums to help craft systems like this. Here we can't really answer questions about "too much" or "too little" because every person will have their own opinion. We answer problems with an actual answer from expert sources. This problem isn't fit for this site, I have to vote to close it.

Comment: It is certainly not too much. Marvel and DC have all four types of superheroes already. But they don't have "magic systems" or attempt to make things self-consistent. I have never seen anyone try and do that.

Answer (score 3):

**Nothing's stopping you just be cautious**

It's fun to imagine a world where superheroes are living alongside wizards, advanced technology, and Batman-like characters. What you're describing is basically just either DC or Marvel. Both have a wide array of superheroes ranging from superhumans to magic-users and so on. It can work to great effect.

The biggest problem is keeping the internal logic straight when there are so many different competing systems to work with.

There need to be clear lines to what a magician can do that a superhuman cannot, with some room for overlap. For example, superhumans might be able to shoot lasers out of their eyes. Magicians either can't or just choose not to do it. Magic is about finesse, not strength, so you'll never see a magician lifting a car with their bare hands. Similarly, superhumans are the opposite, they're about raw strength and nothing more, so, while there are some smart ones, you'll never see them bother with subtlety when they can use force.

I also suggest certain types of magic are weak against some and ridiculously strong against others. Specifically, traditional magic is weak to tech, superpowers are weak to magic, Charles Atlas is weak against superpowers. Charles Atlas types are surprisingly good with tech. Or whatever pattern of matchups you think would work best for your story.

I think it would be best to have a "soft magic system" where you can play loose and fast with the rules a bit. The rules are fluid and flexible rather than rigid and unchanging. That way you have more breathing room as an author.

The biggest problem is having so many elements to the story that you can't keep your rules straight. Either be incredibly specific or keep the rules vague enough that strange happenings are basically the status quo.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you could simply have overlap with different magic systems, with each system achieving similar things, albeit in a different way.

We have a version of this in Avatar: The Last Airbender. Mastery in any element can be used to fight, but how you fight depends on what element you use. Fire-benders specialize in concentrated force, Earth-benders focus on endurance and outlasting an opponent, Air-benders specialize in evasion and movement, and Water-benders redirect attacks and turn their foe's own energy against them. All 4 are viable tactics for success in combat.